# method argument is not accessible by name inside method

Tags: java, android

Is it a bug in android studio or java, don't know. I was working on an astronomy application. I have created a method to get phase of moon. It takes two argument but only one argument is accessible by name. In debugger it says argument not found but when I assign to some other variable, it gets assigned. No runtime error in execution.
[image]

Argument that is not accessible is `moon_degrees` but when I assign it's value to `variable moon_degree` it works.

Don't know what's happening

Android studio Version 2.0

windows 7 X86

Answer (score 0):

This may be a known bug:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37019591

You could provide your case to the bug report to help to find the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your method argument is accessing inside method, but if you want to see inside method variable value in Debugger, please declare this inside variable Global.